# Pedal length/curvature differential relation

Tags: geometry, differential-geometry

By constructing differential triangles in polar coordinates in the plane show that

$$ \dfrac{dp}{ds}= \dfrac{t}{R} = t \,\kappa$$

[ pedal length $p$ , tangent projection $t$, instant radius $R$ , curvature $\kappa$, arc  $s$].

EDIT 1:

In place of $(12), (13)$ I obtained by scalar arc differentiation the RHS as  $ (t \kappa, 1- \kappa \,p )$ respectively in which sign of  $\kappa $ is the opposite.

I reasoned for the new *latter Equation* (13) taking the example of an involute of a circle.... since the magnitude of normal is constant (= radius of circle from which a taut string is unwound), it should vanish, so that

$$ \kappa p = +1,\, p = +R $$

But Robert Lewis and by implication and also Ted Shifrin put the sign as

$$ \kappa p = -1,\, p = -R $$

which should be reconciled.

[image: Either pdash at Inflection]

Comment: I added the "differential geometry" tag to your post.

Comment: Thanks for  DG tag.

Comment: For starters, in your example drawing, there seems to be a sign issue. $t$ needs to have a sign.

Comment: @RobertLewis  Please comment about sign after my edit in question.

Comment: No, I didn't say it should *always* be $-$ ... See my answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know much about "differential triangles in polar coordinates in the plane", but here's a pretty short proof, based on the [Frenet-Serret](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Frenet%E2%80%93Serret_formulas) apparatus, which is more or less coordinate independent:

Let the curve be given by $\vec r(s)$, where $\vec r(s)$ is the vector from the origin $O$ to the point on the curve corresponding to the parameter value $s$, the arc-length from some fixed but arbitrary point (on the curve).  Then $\vec T(s)$, the unit tangent vector field along $\vec r(s)$ is given by

$\vec T(s) = \dot {\vec r}(s), \tag 1$

where the "$\dot {}$" denotes $d/ds$, *viz*.

$\dot {\vec r} = \dfrac{d{\vec r}}{ds}.  \tag 2$

From $\vec T(s)$ we derive the *unit normal* vector $\vec N(s)$ and curvature $\kappa(s)$ *via*

$\dot {\vec T}(s) = \kappa(s) \vec N(s); \tag 3$

we can then express $\vec r(s)$ in the $\vec T(s)$-$\vec N(s)$ frame:

$\vec r(s) = \langle \vec T(s), \vec r(s) \rangle \vec T(s) + \langle \vec N(s), \vec r(s) \rangle \vec N(s); \tag 4$

then we can take

$t(s) = \langle \vec T(s), \vec r(s) \rangle \tag 5$

and

$p(s) = \langle \vec N(s), \vec r(s) \rangle; \tag 6$

thus, from (6),

$\dfrac{dp(s)}{ds} = \dfrac{d}{ds}\langle \vec N(s), \vec r(s) \rangle = \langle \dot {\vec N}(s), \vec r(s) \rangle + \langle \vec N(s), \dot {\vec r}(s) \rangle;  \tag 7$

now by (1)

$ \langle \vec N(s), \dot {\vec r}(s) \rangle =  \langle \vec N(s), \vec T(s) \rangle = 0, \tag 8$

so

$\dfrac{dp(s)}{ds} = \langle \dot {\vec N}(s), \vec r(s) \rangle;  \tag 9$

from [Frenet-Serret](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Frenet%E2%80%93Serret_formulas),

$\dot {\vec N}(s) = -\kappa(s) \vec T(s), \tag{10}$

so (9) becomes

$\dfrac{dp(s)}{ds} = \langle -\kappa(s) \vec T(s), \vec r(s) \rangle = -\kappa(s) \langle \vec T(s), \vec r(s) \rangle = -\kappa(s) t(s).  \tag {12}$

We note there is, as Ted Shifrin indicates in his comment, "a sign issue"; that is, our formula for $dp/ds$ gives a result with opposite sign of the corresponding equation in the text of the question, $dp/ds = \kappa t$.  Apparently this could be resolved by taking $p = - \langle \vec r, \vec N \rangle$, but present definition of $p(s)$, as the $\vec N(s)$ component of $\vec r(s)$ in the $T(s)$-$N(s)$ frame, is sufficiently natural and clean that I am inclined not to mess with it.  So there we have it.  Hope this helps.

***Note Added in Edit, Saturday 12 August 2017 10:40 AM PST:***  It is perhaps worth adding that there is a corresponding equation for $dt/ds$, based upon (5), to wit:

$\dfrac{dt(s)}{ds} = \langle \dot {\vec T}(s), \vec r(s) \rangle + \langle \vec T(s), \dot {\vec r}(s) \rangle$
$ = \langle \kappa(s) \vec N(s), \vec r(s) \rangle + \langle \vec T(s), \vec T(s) \rangle = \kappa(s) p(s) + 1. \tag {13}$

Curious.  Engaging.  ***End of Note.***

Comment: In the usual context of support lines, we always have $p\ge 0$, so there is a sign issue perhaps with your definition of $p$ as well. Our arguments are very close to identical, but not quite.

Comment: @TedShifrin:  though I'd heard of them, I didn't know what a pedal line was until I studied the diagram in this question; so I gave the problem a try to fix what I had learned.  I couldn't figure out the exact definition from the diagram so I winged it.  As I said in my post I could have taken $p = -\langle \vec r, \vec N \rangle$.  Anyway, thanks for the input.

Comment: No, the sign may well change at points where $\vec r$ and $\vec T$ are parallel.

Comment: No, I  think we are talking about $p^{'}$ sign changeover at inflection, please see  modified sketch.

Answer (score 3):

I haven't worked out an "infinitesimal" argument, but I can give a very elementary argument, which also clarifies the sign issue on $t$. By the definition of the support line and $p$, we have the equation 
$$p = \boldsymbol\alpha \cdot (\cos\theta,\sin\theta).$$
Differentiating with respect to arclength, we get
$$p'(s) = \boldsymbol\alpha'(s)\cdot (\cos\theta,\sin\theta) + \boldsymbol\alpha(s)\cdot (-\sin\theta,\cos\theta)\theta'(s).$$
The first term is $0$ because $(\cos\theta,\sin\theta)$ is normal to the support line (which is the tangent line). $\theta'(s)=\kappa(s)$ (almost by definition for a plane curve), and $t=\boldsymbol\alpha\cdot (-\sin\theta,\cos\theta)$.

Comment: I think in your original question, you should think of the relevance of $R = 1/\kappa$ in terms of using $ds = R\,d\theta$ for one side of your infinitesimal triangle.